# How to retain sorting order of columns in sencha grid

Tags: extjs, extjs-grid

I have a grid with few columns which are sortable. Currently if user clicks on any column, it gets sorted, and at the same time grid clears existing sort. I want grid to retain the sort of existing column as well.

Here is the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3mg5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiColumnSort config on your grid. By doing it this way your grid will not clear the existing column sort option. However, you should also give option to user to clear the sort state.

Here is the working solution - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3mg6

Comment: thank you so much DEVENDRA HALDANKAR it helps me lot